# Teshuva knowing that I'm likely to sin again

Tags: sin, yom-kippur, repentance-teshuvah

Every year I have a very similar list of aveiros that I want to stop.  Practically, I know that it is too much to expect myself to have completely stopped all of them by next Rosh Hashana, so I prioritise and try to focus on some specific ones.  However, that means that I'm effectively trying to do teshuva for some aveiros that I know that I'm likely to do again, and also that I'm likely to be doing aveiros that I intend to do teshuva for later.

I know that there is a principle that you can't do teshuva for an aveira if you do it while thinking that you are going to do teshuva later.  But there are aveiros that I do that I regret even while I am doing them, but don't feel that I have the strength to stop (yet), but I would like to get to that point in the future.  Does that mean that I'm never going to be able to do teshuva, because I intended to while I was doing the aveira, or does it only mean in a situation where someone is only doing the aveira because they think that they can do teshuva later and wipe it out?

Either way, I know that Yom Kippur wipes out aveiros and makes a clean slate, but it almost feels wrong that I can go through Yom Kippur and have my aveiros cleared off the sheet knowing even during YK that I am just going to do them again.  Can I really expect those aveiros that I'm expecting to continue doing to be wiped clean by YK?

Comment: I once heard, don’t recall a source, that when a person does Teshuva and make a small change for the better, he’s considered a new person. Any aveiros he does after that is a new cheshbon. So although he knows he will sin again, it’s like a baby that we know will sin in their lifetime, they are still clean of sin right now

Comment: @Chatzkel thanks. I feel like you are spending so much time responding to my questions atm!  May it be a merit for you for next year - ksiva vchasima tova

Comment: Amen! Thank you. You too, a sweet happy new year!

Comment: A rebbi in my yeshiva gave a shmuz I think you would like (about this subject), you want me to send it to you?

Comment: @KovyJacob if it isn't too much trouble, thanks

Comment: My Rav gives a Nach shiur after Mincha on Shabbos afternoon and we just finished the story of Naaman.  I found it really interesting that he asks for mechila from Hashem at the time when he is doing teshuva that he will sin again in future.  Elisha HaNovi tells him to "go in peace" after, which isn't excusing it, but I'm wondering whether I should take that as a message that we learned that this week that I should be at peace about this and not drive myself mad over it!

Comment: @wizzardm42 If your teshuva is an emesdig teshuva at the time you did it, it is teshuva. Even if you know you'll do it again, as long as it was a real teshuva Hashem accepts it.

Comment: @wizzardmr42 How should I send it to you?

Comment: @KovyJacob any chance you can post a link to it then other people can see it too?

Comment: @KovyJacob "Even if you know you'll do it again, as long as it was a real teshuva Hashem accepts it." This seems to directly contradict what the Rambam says, and contradict itself. "real teshuvah" includes abandoning the sin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RAv Aharon Feldman said in a shiur (I forget his sources) -that he said was inspired by a similar question someone asked him- that it would be a partial teshuvah.

Especially if you are doing what you can to better your situation overall. As you daven, beg Hashem to help you overcome whatever issues you have to be able to serve Him better.

And keep in mind that whatever progress you make is still an improvement and very worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

I heard that the main thing is to focus on your direction through introspection which we have a hard time doing but is the key to realize ways where we could change our direction in life